# Unexpected behaviour while creating a eclipse project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a java project with all the binaries, source files and libraries together. 
I have placed it in an eclipse workspace and for some purpose I wanted to convert it into an eclipse project. 
I wrote the following lines of code for the following task.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
IPath rootPath = root.getLocation();
File rootFile = rootPath.toFile();
File[] contents = rootFile.listFiles();


for(File file : contents) {
    if(file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().startsWith(".")) {


        File[] projectContents = file.listFiles();

        //First create a simple project of type org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject:
        IProject project = root.getProject(file.getName());
        if(!project.exists()) {
            project.create(null);
        }
        else {
            project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
        }
        if (!project.isOpen()) {
            project.open(null);
        }



        IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder("bin");

        if(!binFolder.exists()) {
            binFolder.create(false, true, null);
        }
        //Now we can create our Java project
        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
        javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);


        <Remaining lines of code>
     }
 }
```

Now I wanted to use my already built class files. So I commented the following lines:

```
        IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder("bin");

        if(!binFolder.exists()) {
            binFolder.create(false, true, null);
        }

        javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);
```

But even now the bin folder was getting created and class files were generated in it. And these class files were not the one which I had since they all had latest time stamp in their properties.

I am pretty sure that it is due to this line.

```
        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening. I did not even added these below lines of code which are specifically for building the project.

```
            if(!javaProject.hasBuildState()) {
                project.build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD, null);
            }
```

I will be grateful if you could also tell me how to convert the java project to eclipse project programmatically using the binaries, source files and libraries which I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use import java project with existing source wizard. 
The other shortcut i personally used is, create a new empty java project in the desired name, copy all the resources (src, lib, etc) of existing java project into the new project except bin and .project file. Then if needed configure the source directories and libraries from project properties.

Comment: I do not want to use the GUI of eclipse, rather do it programatically.